# How do I write a loop to include an object with string value if the object doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of objects as show below, I'm going to *filter* out the objects and add into another object of objects (the reason is that I will be storing it into firestore and it only accepts non-arrays) so I'm just going to keep things indexed with numbers but how do I automatically add an object into the list of objects if the object name is not there? (Default object with a value in string)

```
let data = [ {name: Cat, choice: one, Date: 11/11/22, Time: 503, food: chicken}, {name: Dog, Date: 11/11/22, Time: 802, food: veggies}, {name: Cat, choice: two, Date: 11/11/22, Time: 105, food: beef} ]

for(let i = 0; i<data.length-1; i++) {
    let savingData = [] 
    if(data[i].choice == "undefined" || "null") {
        data[i].choice = "zero";
    }
    savingData.push({
        name: data[i].name
        choice: data[i].choice //missing choices will default to zero as  string
        food: data[i].food
    });
}

for(let j = 0; j<savingData.length-1; j++) {
    let objectSavingData = Object.assign({}, savingData[j]);
}
```

Does not work - did I miss something? or maybe the error is not in this portion of code.. (data structure changed due to its lengthyness, data has arrays of 150+ and object names of over 40, I just simplified it to this but all the data entry are in string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map function to archive it.

Also use [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) & default value.

Here is a snipecode.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Cat", choice: "one", Date: "11/11/22", Time: 503, food: "chicken" },
  { name: "Dog", Date: "11/11/22", Time: 802, food: "veggies" },
  { name: "Cat", choice: "two", Date: "11/11/22", Time: 105, food: "beef" }
]

const savingData = data.map((record) => {
  const { name, choice = 0, Date: date, Time: time, food } = record;
  return { name, choice, date, time, food };
});

console.log(savingData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`let savingData = [] ;` >>> this need to be declared before 'for loop';
`i<data.length-1; >>> i<data.length`
`let objectSavingData = Object.assign({}, savingData[j]);` - you are 
  assigning new object to objectSavingData...also object.assing just 
  merge/overwrite properties.this will not work
```